# Can I use NW SDK client 7.5 for accessing NW 7.4 SAP server?

Tags: saprfc, sap-basis, netweaver

I have SAP NETWEAVER 7.4 installed on my SAP. Can I use 7.5 client libraries to connect to the server?
I have tried to connect to the server using [SapNwRfc](https://github.com/huysentruitw/SapNwRfc) library, but got an exception
"RFC_LOGON_FAILURE with message: 00024error during logon".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/nwrfcsdk.html)?. Scroll down to the documentation section.

Comment: Yes I have, and I have assumed that it could have something to do with necessary authorizations, but I also need to know whether is it safe to use the newer version (7.5) of SDK against the older one (7.4) on the server?

Answer (score 2):

SAP's RFC protocol is downwards compatible. In general, you can use NW RFC SDK 7.50 also for newer and older NetWeaver AS ABAP releases at least back to the really old R/3 release 4.6.
Of course, if using some newer RFC protocol features (like WebSocket RFC for example), then also the ABAP back-end has to support it. Available RFC features are signaled to the partner in the protocol's internal RFC headers.

If you are getting an RFC_LOGON_FAILURE, this has other reasons and depends on the back-end's configuration and the used RFC logon parameters, but not on the used NW RFC library version.